# What is InstallIQ updater for, why is it on my Windows XP machine and do I really need it?

Tags: windows-xp, updates, installer

What is InstallIQ updater for, why is it on my Windows XP machine and do I really need it? I searched Google, but I have been unable to find out any usable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstallIQ is a software toolkit that developers can use to package their software, allowing users to download and run a single file to install the packaged software.  The most common example is InstallShield, but there are others.  InstallIQ seems to be aimed at developers who want to increase revenue by bundling their software with assorted crapware, some of which is of dubious value and questionable quality.  Fortunately, software that is usually packaged with InstallIQ (like Digsby) may also be available in less annoying packaging.  My advice is to identify which software on your system was installed with InstallIQ, uninstall it along with all crapware that came with it, find alternative installation methods for the software you need and use that instead.  [This HowToGeek post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2310/be-careful-not-to-install-junk-software-with-digsby/) has some examples.

Also, as a general rule, **always** perform custom installs and disable installation of anything extra that you don't really need.  That includes most browser toolbars, which are almost all terrible.

Comment: +1, helpful answer. How might I identify which software on your system was installed with InstallIQ? I have nothing to do with Digsby.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: That information is probably in your registry somewhere.  I could tell you for sure if I installed Digsby using its InstallIQ installer, but I would prefer not to do that.  If you get stuck, let me know and I'll install it in a throwaway virtual machine.  Meanwhile, you might be able to figure out what you installed with InstallIQ by trying to remember something you installed where it kept asking you if you wanted to install various pieces of crapware.  Apparently with InstallIQ, each of these offers has its own screen and there may have been quite a few of them.  Ring any bells?

Comment: I always am very careful about not installing those pieces of crapware. I guess I must have missed some switch. No need to install Digsby - as I already noted, I have never installed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> InstallIQ™ Updater keeps the software you’ve download via InstallIQ™ current and up-to-date with the latest security patches, bug fixes, and feature improvements. InstallIQ™ Updater also provides convenient information on the software you’ve installed in one spot.

Removal

Windows XP Users:

Click the Start Menu
Select the Control Panel
Select the Add or Remove Programs
Locate this product from the "Currently Installed Programs" list
Click Change/Remove

Vista and Windows 7 Users:
Click the Start Menu
Select the Control Panel
Under the Programs heading, click Uninstall a program
Locate this product from the "Programs and Features" list
Click Uninstall

Even easier in Windows 7 Click Start menu, select "Search" (immediately above start) type 'Intalliqupdater' which will appear on list with the option to "uninstall' just click this and then follow the prompts.

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

> **What is InstallIQ™ Updater?**
>   InstallIQ™ Updater keeps the software you’ve download via InstallIQ™ current and up-to-date with the latest security patches, bug fixes, and feature improvements. InstallIQ™ Updater also provides convenient information on the software you’ve installed in one spot.

more info if you follow [this link](http://answers.recipester.org/question/944/What%20is%20InstallIQ%20Updater%3F) (at bottom of page)

My advice is to just uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks. That's one of the links I found. As you can see there is no real information except that it implies that it is some sort of "money making" device. I sure would like to know more.

Answer (score 1):

The InstallIQ updater has a tab that shows Installed Programs as well. This is how to know what programs to uninstall.